# Check if Stylesheet with ID is loaded - Then execute function

Tags: jquery

I have a stylesheet that is loaded only on certain pages. When this stylesheet is loaded, it capplies styles I do not want.

Now I do not have access to the stylesheet, but I can apply jQuery to the pages...

How detect if a stylesheet with id:SupersizedCSS-css is loaded, and if it is, I want to apply some styles to the Page...

Code:

```
       if($('link[rel="stylesheet"]').attr('id') == 'SupersizedCSS-css'){
           alert('Stylesheet loaded - Apply some styles');
       }
```

My code does not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try that:

```
$(function () {
    $('#SupersizedCSS-css').on('load', function () {
        alert('Stylesheet loaded - Apply some styles');
    });
});
```

But, if you mean to check if page contains this link:

```
$(function () {
    if ($('#SupersizedCSS-css').length) {
        alert('Stylesheet loaded - Apply some styles');
    }
});
```